# How to access template variable values of type ViewContainerRef?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am rendering components using `ViewContainerRef` inside a template. However, I want to access the value set in the template dynamically on the component. I read articles that said values can be accessed when the template is accessed using `ElementRef` since there we have a `nativeElement` but I didn't find any alternative in the case of `ViewContainerRef`. I am not sure but will I get the values set in template in `context` object?

Here is the sample I am trying to build: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfaxuj

Answer (score 1):

I could only achieve passing data through the same function that is instantiating the components, not through HTML as you requested... I'm not sure it is possible with ng-template... maybe if you change to a ng-container and then reference a template you can get the right context, other than that I'm not sure...

In the following example I could pass item to HelloComponent basing on the index of my `items` array
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmnpku?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Anyways, if you only need to send data to your component I'd say this is a better practice rather than sending it through html reference

Comment: Yes sure it is. But let's say the `dataItem` is populated in table using `async` pipe and at data time I won't be having access of data inside `dataItem` on the component side to manipulate and send data to component inside the `ng-template`

Comment: You could pipe map your data observable and send the result to previously created dynamicComponentRef.instance, it would need to be an async call with setTimeout or something

Comment: I've updated the `stackblitz` example and it worked...It is not the fanciest solution but you could do a decorator or some helper function to avoid making this logic everytime